# Adding a Groups Claim to a Service Principal via Azure CLI

Tags: azure-cli, azure-service-principal

It is obvious how to create a Service Principal (App Registration) via Azure CLI:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "My Service Principal" --scopes /subscriptions/the-subscription-guid
```

From the Azure Portal, you can add a **Claims Group** to the generated service principal, as such:

[image]

How can I add this via the Azure CLI at the time of creation of principal or after creating it? I did not find the documentation to do so.

Comment: Well according to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest) their is no way to ad group claims using azure cli . So as far as I know only the portal path to assigning group claims exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For a service principal, you can add an optional claim and group claims as follows:*

*Using command:*

```bash
az ad app create --display-name "xxx" --optional-claims @manifest.json
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

***Group Claim:***

*myjson file*:

```json
{
"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup",
"optionalClaims": {
"saml2Token": [
{
"name": "groups",
"essential": false,
"additionalProperties": []
]
}
],
"idToken": [
{
"name": "groups",
"essential": false
}
]
}
}
```

*Use below Az CLI command:*

```bash
az ad app update --id "<AppID>" --set groupMembershipClaims=All
```

Refer [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims)